# WebView - User has scrolled

Tags: scroll, webview, objective-c

I cannot figure out how to have a WebView in Objective-c detect when a scroll has been made. I have looked at the `WebFrameLoadDelegate:` and found `didChangeLocationWithinPageForFrame:` method, but that did seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to detect the webview is scrolling by using javascript. If you do a quick google search on "uiwebview javascript" you'll see plenty of examples on how to have javascript run in the uiwebivew. Once you get the javascript to detect the scroll occurring then you have the javascript change window.location to something fake and implement the "webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:" delegate to execute objective-c code. Return NO from the delegate method to not load the request.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you are using a UIWebView (iOS - Cocoa Touch) or WebView (OS X - Cocoa).

iOS (iOS 5 and later):

UIWebView exposes its UIScrollView, and you can set the scroll view's delegate and then implement the delegate scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method (adding  to your class's @interface declaration first, of course; this example is in a UIViewController subclass):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [_webView.scrollView setDelegate:self];
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // do something in response to scroll
    }
}
```

OS X:

Add an observer for the NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification of the WebView (this example is in an NSWindowController subclass):

```
- (id)initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                  selector:@selector(_scrollDetected)
                                                  name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:_webView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)_scrollDetected {
   // do something in response to scroll
}
```

Comment: NSViewBoundsDidChange gets fired from a private subview of the web view, not the web view itself. And it's whenever any scroll happens, not just user-initiated. This doesn't appear to work for me on the Mac running Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, you can detect it by subscribing to `NSScrollViewWillStartLiveScrollNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mySelector:)
  name:NSScrollViewWillStartLiveScrollNotification object:nil];
```

I pass `nil` as the object parameter because when I get it, it doesn't appear to actually come from the `enclosingScrollView` on the `WebView`. And there is no scroll view property on [WKWebView in Yosemite](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014624).  So when handling it, you have to check if it's your web view sending it (being paranoid about type safety):

```
-(void)handleScroll:(id)sender
{
  if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSNotification class]])
  {
    NSNotification *notif = (NSNotification *)sender;
    if ([notif.object isKindOfClass:[NSView class]])
    {
        NSView *view = (NSView *)notif.object;
        if ([view isDescendantOf:self.webView])
        {
           //Handle scroll here
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have only tried this descendent-checking thing with `WebView`, so if you're using `WKWebView`, YMMV.

There are other scroll notifications listed in the [NSScrollView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/).